# Find the remainder when $19^{22}$ is divided by $92$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the remainder when $19^{22}$ is divided by $92$.

Will Euler's totient function help us?

Comment: We know that $92=23\cdot4$. Can you work it out modulo $23$ and modulo $4$? Then what?

Comment: **Hint:** $22=2^4+2^2+2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $22=2^4+2^2+2$, so $$\color{red}{19^{22}=19^{2^4}19^{2^2}19^2}.\tag{A}$$

Now $$\begin{align}\color{green}{19^2}&\color{green}{\equiv 85\pmod{92}},\tag{1}\\
\color{blue}{19^{2^2}}&\equiv (19^2)^2\equiv 85^2\color{blue}{\equiv49\pmod{92}},\tag{2} \\
19^{2^3}&\equiv (19^{2^2})^2\equiv 49^2\equiv 9\pmod{92},\text{ and} \\
\color{magenta}{19^{2^4}}&\equiv (19^{2^3})^2\equiv 9^2\color{magenta}{\equiv 81\pmod{92}}\tag{3}\end{align}$$ all give $$\color{red}{19^{22}}\equiv \color{magenta}{81}\times \color{blue}{49}\times\color{green}{85} \equiv 1\pmod{92}$$ via $(\text A)$, $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$.

Comment: @SatnivMashkaria Is that clear now? This method can be generalised to similar situation too. Can you see why? :)

Answer (score 6):

Using [Carmichael](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) function, $$\lambda(92)=\text{lcm}(22,2)=22$$

---

Alternatively,

$\displaystyle92=4\cdot23,$

$\displaystyle19\equiv-1\pmod4\implies19^{22}\equiv(-1)^{22}\equiv1$

and using Fermat's Little Theorem, $\displaystyle19^{22}\equiv1\pmod{23}$

$\displaystyle\implies19^{22}\equiv1\pmod{\text{lcm}(4,23)} $

Comment: @SatvikMashkaria, How about this?

Comment: yeah it is correct but for INMO(Indian National Mathematical Olympiad) I think there should be a simpler solution.......

Comment: @SatvikMashkaria, Please find the edited version

Comment: @SatvikMashkaria, you might have not heard about the Carmichael function, but you certainly went through *order* and maybe *primitive roots*. You can rephrase his first answer to your needs using these concepts. Both solutions are very elementary and elegant. +1

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\phi (92)=44,$$ $(19^{22})^2=19^{44}$, and $(92, 19)=1$. What theorem can you now use?

Comment: Then we will get $k^2={1(\mod{92})}$. Does that mean $k=1$? where k is required remainder

Comment: There are four non-congruent solutions to $k^2\equiv1\pmod{92}$ so we need something more :-)